# How to insert choosen value from spinner to SQLite?

Tags: java, sqlite

Good day,

How to insert value choosen from spinner to SQLite database? 
I created array in strings.xml.  Then in Activity.java this code:

```
 spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.Array2, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then this (also in Activity):

```
    Button AddHere;
    Spinner spinner;
    DataBase db;
    db = new DataBase(this);

    AddHere = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddHere);

        AddHere.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String SpinnerEdit = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                boolean isInserted = db.insert(SpinnerEdit);
                if (isInserted == true)
                    Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Data NOT Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Then in DBHelper.java :

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "Testing.db" , null, 1); }

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("Create table Testing (Spinner text);");

}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Testing");
    onCreate(db);
}
public boolean insert (String SpinnerEdit)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put ("Category", SpinnerEdit);
    long ins = db.insert("Testing", null, contentValues);
    if (ins==-1) return false;
    else return true;
}}
```

But "Data is NOT inserted." Where is the problem and how to fix it? Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: @forpas I changed, sorry, forgot to update here. Now done but still data is not being inserted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
contentValues.put ("Category", SpinnerEdit);
```

puts a value for the column `Category` but your table does not contain such a column.
In the create statement of your table there is only 1 column named `Spinner`.